# Check if user are friend to display data in members-loop buddyprress

Tags: buddypress

Can someone please help me out, I have a profile field named BB Pin and i use

BB Pin:`<?php bp_member_profile_data('field=BB Pin');?>`

to show the data in members-loop.php and it work fine but i want to do it so that if you are not friend the field value is ***********.

Something like

if is friend{

BB Pin:`<?php bp_member_profile_data('field=BB Pin');?>`

}
else{ 
************.

Thanks for you help.

Regards

**Update:**

I have just tried the below code in the members-loop.php but did not work.

`<?php
global $bp; $friend = BP_Friends_Friendship::check_is_friend( $bp->loggedin_user->id, $bp->displayed_user->id ); if ( $bp->loggedin_user->id || $friend == 'is_friend') : ?> echo <?php bp_member_profile_data('field=BB Pin');?> <?php else : ?> echo *************** <?php endif; ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Check if logged in user is friend or not please use below code:

```
global $bp;
$is_friend = friends_check_friendship( $bp->loggedin_user->id, $bp->displayed_user->id );

if($is_friend) {
   BB Pin:<?php bp_member_profile_data('field=BB Pin');?>
} else{
   BB Pin: ***;
}
```

Comment: unfortunately, your code is not working. it just break my members directory. please be reminded that i want to use the code in members-loop.php.    regards

Answer (score 0):

```
$is_friend = friends_check_friendship( bp_loggedin_user_id(), bp_displayed_user_id() );

if($is_friend) {
  BB Pin:<?php bp_member_profile_data('field=BB Pin');?>
} else{
BB Pin: ***;
```

This one should work in the loop! You can´t use the global Variable $bp in the loop, but there are other variables for that particular task. In this case I just changed

```
$bp->loggedin_user->id, $bp->displayed_user->id
```

to the ones in my code example!